# How do I make a pop-up window with Scene2D?

Tags: java, libgdx, menu, scene2d

I have a main-menu screen with a logo and a bunch of buttons. When the Login-button is pressed, I pop up a dialogue asking for a username and password.

This works fine, other than the "popping up". At the moment the new the dialogue box just shifts everything about, but I'd want to position it *over* the current scene.

I'm just learning Scene2D.

Answer (score 11):

Dialog is better suited for modal pop-up windows, and it includes a "button" and "content" table already in the window (as the [docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui) say). You can grab these tables with getButtonTable() or getContentTable().

The dialog makes it easy to work with pop up windows. For example, here is a confirmation dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Warning", skin, "dialog") {
    public void result(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("result "+obj);
    }
};
dialog.text("Are you sure you want to quit?");
dialog.button("Yes", true); //sends "true" as the result
dialog.button("No", false);  //sends "false" as the result
dialog.key(Keys.Enter, true); //sends "true" when the ENTER key is pressed
dialog.show();
```

You can use other objects for, say, Yes/No/Cancel options.

Comment: Is it possible to have the dialog set its size automatically based on its contents? Looks like it's too small with the example above..

Comment: I guess it's possible by calling pack() method :)

Answer (score 0):

Right well, since no one has replied, I will post my solution.

When adding Actors to the Stage, rather than doing:

```
stage.add(actor);
```

Which adds a Cell with the given Actor in it, I done the following:

```
stage.addActor(actor);
```

I was then free to overlap actors and move/scale/rotate them via tweening. The only probably I currently see with this is the absolute positioning of Widgets.

In order to position them you have to call:

```
actor.setPosition(x, y);
```

So it could be a little difficult when dealing with Android devices of different aspect ratios and resolutions.

Comment: absolute position is not so much of a problem as long as you set a static world size and use a viewport with your stage.  It'll handle scaling, stretching, and other obscure properites of dealing with aspect ratios and resolutions.